# How to change color schemes in bar graphs using plotly for R?

Tags: r, plotly, r-plotly

I want to use a different color scheme for my bar graph using the plotly library, its code is looking like this right now:

```
library(plotly)

p <- plot_ly(
 x=c("1","2", "3", "4", "5", "6", "7", "8", "9"),
 y=c(0.79, 0.57, 0.57, 0.59, 0.46, 0.38, 0.33, 0.57),
 name = "2007",
 type = "bar"
)
p

p2 <- add_trace(
  p,
  x=c("1","2", "3", "4", "5", "6", "7", "8", "9"),
  y=c(0.79, 0.57, 0.57, 0.59, 0.46, 0.38, 0.25, 0.58),
  name = "2008",
  type = "bar")
p2
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Do you mean something like this:

```
p <- plot_ly(
 x=c("1","2", "3", "4", "5", "6", "7", "8", "9"),
 y=c(0.79, 0.57, 0.57, 0.59, 0.46, 0.38, 0.33, 0.57),
 name = "2007",
 type = "bar", marker = list(color = toRGB("yellow"))
)
p

p2 <- add_trace(
  p,
  x=c("1","2", "3", "4", "5", "6", "7", "8", "9"),
  y=c(0.79, 0.57, 0.57, 0.59, 0.46, 0.38, 0.25, 0.58),
  name = "2008",
  type = "bar", marker = list(color = toRGB("black")))
p2
```